# .onCheckedListeners on multiple groups of checkboxes in Android Studio won't work

Tags: android, checkbox

I have tried to have multiple groups of checkboxes where only one can be checked but on the attempt of implementing this functionality to a 2nd group of checkboxes the app crashes when i try to go to the activity containing those groups of checkboxes. The auton group of check boxes are working with only one able to be checked out of the 5 but even since I tried to add the same thing with the port_    ones I have had no luck.

```
    auton_nothing = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.nothing_cb);
    auton_touch= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.touchdefense_cb);
    auton_cross= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cross_cb);
    auton_high= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.hg_cb);
    auton_low= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.lg_cb);

    auton_nothing.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            auton_nothing.setChecked(b);
            auton_touch.setChecked(false);
            auton_cross.setChecked(false);
            auton_high.setChecked(false);
            auton_low.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    auton_touch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            auton_nothing.setChecked(false);
            auton_touch.setChecked(b);
            auton_cross.setChecked(false);
            auton_high.setChecked(false);
            auton_low.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    auton_cross.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            auton_nothing.setChecked(false);
            auton_touch.setChecked(false);
            auton_cross.setChecked(b);
            auton_high.setChecked(false);
            auton_low.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    auton_high.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            auton_nothing.setChecked(false);
            auton_touch.setChecked(false);
            auton_cross.setChecked(false);
            auton_high.setChecked(b);
            auton_low.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    auton_low.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            auton_nothing.setChecked(false);
            auton_touch.setChecked(false);
            auton_cross.setChecked(false);
            auton_high.setChecked(false);
            auton_low.setChecked(b);
        }
    });
    port_na= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.portc_na_cb);
    port_na.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            port_na.setChecked(b);
            port_attempt.setChecked(false);
            port_diff.setChecked(false);
            port_easy.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    port_attempt.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            port_na.setChecked(false);
            port_attempt.setChecked(b);
            port_diff.setChecked(false);
            port_easy.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    port_diff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            port_na.setChecked(false);
            port_attempt.setChecked(false);
            port_diff.setChecked(b);
            port_easy.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
    port_easy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            port_na.setChecked(false);
            port_attempt.setChecked(false);
            port_diff.setChecked(false);
            port_easy.setChecked(b);
        }
    });
    port_attempt= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.portc_attempted_cb);
    port_diff= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.portc_difficult_cb);
    port_easy= (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.portc_easy_cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this........

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
  >

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:checkedButton="1"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/check_a"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox_first"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/check_b"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox_second"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/check_c"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox_third"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private CheckBox checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_first);
        checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_second);
        checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox_third);
    }

    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

        switch(view.getId()) {

            case R.id.checkBox1:

                    checkBox2.setChecked(false);
                    checkBox3.setChecked(false);

                break;

            case R.id.checkBox2:

                    checkBox3.setChecked(false);
                    checkBox1.setChecked(false);

                break;

            case R.id.checkBox3:

                    checkBox1.setChecked(false);
                    checkBox2.setChecked(false);

                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I implemented it but the OnCheckboxClick is grayed or never used and I ran and tested it and it doesn't work